# (TRANSACT SQL) how to create Master-Detail in a row using sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables

```
table1
------
ID
NAME
ADDRESS

table2
-------
ID
PHONE
EMAIL
```

how can i create report like this

```
------------------------------------


01   Dave   123 Veneu

     555-5  A@YAHOO.COM
     66-66  B@Yahoo.co.id
     213-1  D@c.com


02   John   23 Park

     322-1  C@you.com
     54-23  D@Net.com
     231-2  me@you.com
```

---

im using sql server 2005 express,, thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your data model correct? It's rare for email addresses and phone numbers to be in a `1-1` relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would ever want to write this in anything other than a report designer, but just for the hell of it:

```
SELECT ID AS Column1, NAME AS Column2, Address AS Column3, ID AS SortColumn1, 1 AS SortColumn2
UNION
SELECT '', PHONE, EMAIL, ID AS SortColumn1, 2 AS SortColumn2
ORDER BY SortColumn1, SortColumn2
```

The output is going to basically be a load of gibberish really, and you've got the two extra columns on the end of to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't.  It's a *general* principle that formatting should not be done in the database layer.

SQL Server should be used to generate data, then your application should process the data, including the formatting.

I would open two queries.  One that loads table one, ordered by the ID column.  And the other that load table two, also ordered by the ID column.  You can then iterate through both record sets at the same time, something like the following pseudo-code...

```
rs1 = SQL.Execute("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY ID")
rs2 = SQL.Execute("SELECT * FROM table2 ORDER BY ID, phone")

rs2.Next()
WHILE rs1.Next()
  Output The Address Info Here
  WHILE rs1.ID = rs2.ID
    Output The Phone/Email Info Here
    rs2.Next()
  END WHILE
END WHILE
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have one-to-many relationship, as in your example (one person has multiple phones and emails), you need to add some kind of link column to the second table, which would contain the ID of the person the email / phone belongs to.

So your table structure should look like this:

```
table1
------
ID
NAME
ADDRESS

table2
-------
ID
TABLE1_ID
PHONE
EMAIL
```

Then, you could query your data using joins:

```
SELECT table1.name, table1.address, table2.phone, table2.email WHERE table2.table1_id = table1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with dems, but if you really need to come up with something like that, the following could work (albeit without the empty lines)

```
 SELECT case 
            when group_rn = 1 then id 
            else ''
        end as id, 
        case 
          when group_rn = 1 then name
          else phone 
        end as name_phone_column, 
        case 
          when group_rn = 1 then address
          else _email 
        end as address_email_column
 FROM (
     SELECT t1.id,
            t1.name,
            t1.address,
            t2.email,
            t2.phone, 
            row_number() over (partition by t1.id order t1.name) as group_rn
     FROM table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
 ) t
 ORDER BY id
```

This assumes that `phone` and `name` both have the same datatype, just like `address` and `email`.